# C++ Loop User input, print odd numbers and then sum

Tags: c++

What am I doing wrong? I'm stuck!
I'm suppose to get numbers from a user and require user to enter the first one smaller than the second number.(While Loop) 
After that I need to output all the odd numbers  (inclusive) and sum all the number between the two input number.
This is what I have so far.

```
int main()
{
int firstNum, secondNum;
int sum = 0;

cout << "Enter two numbers." << endl;
cin >> firstNum >> secondNum;
while (firstNum > secondNum){
        cout << "Invalid entry!" << endl;
cout << "First number must be less than the second number." << endl;
cin >> firstNum >> secondNum;
   } if (firstNum < secondNum){
            for(int i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; i++){
                cout << i << endl;
    }
//make a loop

//cout << << endl; //print all the odd numbers inside the loop
//cout << sum << endl;  //print the sum
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was going to fix the formatting (to make the code readable) however you have a mismatch in your { and }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an error?

in this part you are printing all the numbers between firstNum and secondNum

```
if (firstNum < secondNum){
        for(int i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; i++){
            cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the odd numbers, you should be incrementing by 2 for every cycle of the loop. Also, you need to check if the `firstNum` is an odd number. If not, you have to start on the next number.

```
if (firstNum % 2 == 0) firstNum++;
for(int i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; i = i + 2){
    cout << i << endl
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check all numbers between `firstNum` and `secondNum`.If the number is odd, print it.Then add all numbers, whether it is odd or not.
Like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; ++i){
if(i%2 ==1 ) cout<<i<<" ";
sum += i;
}
```